# Think python exercise 6.4

Tags: python

A number, a, is a power of b if it is divisible by b and a/b is a power of b. Write a function called is_power that takes parameters a and b and returns True if a is a power of b. Note: you will have to think about the base case.
I found this peace of code as it's solution:

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if (a % b == 0):
        return True
        if (a/b == 1):
            return True
        else:
            (is_power (a/b, b) )
    else:
        return False
```

But I guess some lines are not necessary. Here is my own code:

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if (a % b == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

1. What is the reason of existence of extra lines?
2. Both codes don't work for float numbers such as is_power(2.25, 1.5). Both, return False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second code is not correct, take the example of 6 and two your function will return true, but 6 is not a power of two .

```
def is_power(a, b):
    while a % b == 0:
        if a == b: return True
        a /= b
    return False

print(is_power(6, 2))
print(is_power(8, 2))
```

for the second example, comparing if two doubles are equal is usually done to a given magnitude like given eps = 0.0000001
a == b => abs(a - b) < eps .

Comment: You can use [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) to compare within a specific margin of error.

Answer (score 3):

To answer part-1 of your question I have to remind you that the question here doesn't ask you to check whether a is divisible by b, but rather it requires you to find out if 'a' can be expressed as (+ve) exponential of 'b' i.e. `a = b^n`

As for part-2 of your question consider the function below, as it works for both integral & floating point inputs.

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return True

    elif (abs(a)>1 and abs(b)>1) or (abs(a)<1 and abs(b)<1):
        return is_power(a/b, b)       
    
    return False
```

The second conditional statement arises from the fact that +ve exponents of any number with an absolute value greater(or less) than 1 will always be greater(or less) than 1. If absolute values of 'a' & 'b' lie on either side of unity then you can never find a +ve exponent such that `a = b^n`

The above function also takes care of the situation when either 'a' or 'b' is 1. In neither of these situations will you be able to find a +ve exponent 'n' such that `a = b^n`.

Answer (score 1):

@mehdi maick thanks for your correct answer. Here's recursive version, by help of your answer, which I was looking for.

```
def is_power2(a, b):
if a % b == 0 :
    if a == b:
        return True
    else:
        return is_power(a/b, b)
return False
```

Answer (score 1):

## helper Function

```
def is_divisible(a, b):
       if a % b == 0:
            return True

      else:   
         return False
```

## main Function

```
def is_power(a, b):   
 if a == b:   
      return True
 elif b == 1:   
      return False

 else:
     return is_divisible(a,b) and is_power(a/b, b)
```

## TEST CASES

```
print("is_power({0},{1}) returns: {2} ".format(10,2,is_power(10,2)))
print("is_power({0},{1}) returns: {2} ".format(27,3,is_power(27,3)))
print("is_power({0},{1}) returns: {2} ".format(1,1,is_power(1,1)))
print("is_power({0},{1}) returns: {2} ".format(10,1,is_power(10,1)))
print("is_power({0},{1}) returns: {2} ".format(3,3,is_power(3,3)))
```

## Outputs

```
is_power(10,2) returns: False
is_power(27,3) returns: True 
is_power(1,1) returns: True 
is_power(10,1) returns: False 
is_power(3,3) returns: True
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason of existence of extra lines?

- The question asks you to think about "Edge Cases". This part of the code "if (a/b == 1)" is handling an edge case.
- Also, the question says "True if a is a power of b". By removing the else part of the loop, you are avoiding this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

We can concise this code even more by simple mentioning the conditions with return function.

As conditions themselves are *boolean*, we can get a simple *True* or *False*:

```
def is_divisible(a,b):
    return a%b==0 and (a/b)%b==0
print(is_divisible(121,11))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_divisible(x, y):
    return x % y == 0

def is_power(a, b):
    if a == 1: #every positive integer that has an exponent of 0 is a power of "1".
        return True 
    elif is_divisible(a, b): #a is divisible by b
        if a == b: #see explanation below
            return True
        elif b == 1 and a != 1: #the only positive integer that is a power of "1" is "1" itself
            return False
        else:
            return is_power(a/b, b) #a/b is a power of b
    return False

# Conditional if a == b, is a safeguard to avoid a/b < b as a result of recursion.
# e.g. a=4, b=2.
# First iteration. 4 % 2 == 0 is True. Then is_power( 4/2, 2 )
# Second iteration 2 % 2 == 0 is True. Then is_power ( 2/2, 2 ).
# Third iteration 1 % 2 == 0 is False.
# 4 is a power of 2. Without this conditional it would mistakenly return false.


print("is_power(10, 2) returns: ", is_power(10, 2))
print("is_power(27, 3) returns: ", is_power(27, 3))
print("is_power(1, 1) returns: ", is_power(1, 1))
print("is_power(10, 1) returns: ", is_power(10, 1))
print("is_power(3, 3) returns: ", is_power(3, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#with edge conditions and negative value of a and b.

def is_power (a,b): 
    if a==1 or a==b: #always true for power of 0, always true for power of 1 
        return True
    elif (a==0 or b==0 or  b==1) or  (b>a and b>0):
        return False
    else:
        if a%b == 0 and is_power (a/b,b):
            return True
        else:
            return False


Test Cases:
is_power(0, 0) returns:  True
is_power(1, 0) returns:  True
is_power(0, 1) returns:  False
is_power(1, 1) returns:  True
is_power(1, 2) returns:  True
is_power(2, 1) returns:  False
is_power(2, 2) returns:  True
is_power(3, 2) returns:  False
is_power(4, 2) returns:  True
is_power(5, 2) returns:  False
is_power(6, 2) returns:  False
is_power(7, 2) returns:  False
is_power(8, 2) returns:  True
is_power(9, 2) returns:  False
is_power(10, 2) returns:  False
is_power(-1, 0) returns:  False
is_power(-1, -1) returns:  True
is_power(1, -1) returns:  True
is_power(0, -1) returns:  False
is_power(-4, 2) returns:  False
is_power(-8, 2) returns:  False
is_power(4, -2) returns:  True
is_power(8, -2) returns:  False
is_power(-4, -2) returns:  False
is_power(-8, -2) returns:  True
is_power(-2, -2) returns:  True
is_power(-2, -4) returns:  False
is_power(-2, -8) returns:  False
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, but remember it will only work for integers not floating point numbers:

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return True

    if a%b != 0:
        return False
    
    return is_power(a/b,b)
```

Also, the code you are using will not just hold true for exponentials but every multiple of 'b'